# Process was killed by singal 11 (SIGSESV)

Tags: gedit

Sorry, I'm new to Ubuntu so the question may be a little bit rude.
My question is that when I connect to Ubuntu it will show some problem.
it says that process was killed by signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R48Lt.png)
I'm not sure how to solve it and what the problem it will bring, but I know that I can't open my file with gedit now.
how can i do to fixed the problem

Comment: SIGSEGV is a segmentation fault - aka a hard crash of the program.  What happens when you run `gedit` in the command line, it may give more insights than your 'collector' tool.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will show these messages when I try to open gedit with the terminal                                                                                                                    
'Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display "localhost:10.0".
Segmentation fault (core dumped)'

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you *"connect to Ubuntu"*? Are you using some kind of remote connection protocol, or tunneling X11 over SSH? What is your local system and Xserver?

Comment: I used a Windows system connected to an Ubuntu virtual machine through SSH. And the software I used is Xmanger.